# Selenium, C# Logtype NullReference

Tags: c#, selenium, browser

With this code

```
driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).ToList()
```

I'm getting NullReference exception,
I want to get the logs of the FireFox Browser

Comment: It would be helpful to post a Stacktrace. Without it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");
            List<LogEntry> logs= driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser).ToList();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should get logs this way:

```
Driver().Manage().Logs.GetLog();
```

By specifying what log you are interested in you can get the browser log, that is:

```
Driver().Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
```

Also remember to setup your driver accordingly:

```
FireFoxOptions options = new FireFoxOptions();
options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
driver = new FireFoxDriver("path to driver", options);
```

Comment: Do I need to change settings on FireFox Browser

Comment: It depends on your needs. You shouldn't need to change any of the default settings in order to get the logs. Does this code work for you, or does your problem still persist? @SNSN

Comment: It works with chrome without problem, thank you very much
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);